# Instrumental Variables: satisfying exclusion criterion with Covariates

Tags: regression, least-squares, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I have encountered a situation wherein I am trying to ascertain the causal effect of X on Y through an IV approach in a cross-country panel study, but the exclusion restriction is not entirely valid. As per my theoretical understanding of the phenomenon, the causal graph looks something like this:
[image: web of causality]

Z is the instrument, W is an observed variable and U is the set of all other factors (measured and unmeasured) that are affecting Y. All variables (X, Y, Z, and W) are time-varying continuous variables.

In this case, the relevance and exchangeability assumptions hold but Z is causing Y through X and W, violating the exclusion criterion. My main question is:
**Is it possible to get an unbiased estimate of the causal effect of X on Y with Z as an instrument and W as a covariate in 2SLS?**

All the econometrics textbooks I have referred to (such as Mostly Harmless) talk about adding covariates to 2SLS in order to achieve conditional exogeneity for the instrument, but none of them discusses the use of covariates to get around a situation like the above. Any suggestions or references would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing $U$ is not measured?

Comment: If you stratified your analysis on values of $W,$ effectively blocking causal information flow through it, then the resulting graph essentially does not contain $W,$ and you can then use 2SLS because it is a classic setup. This strategy also takes care of the backdoor path $X\leftarrow W\to Y.$